# FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ia', but it was: a custom Oa object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

Not sure why I am getting this error, here's my setup. this error only happens for firestore. Auth, functions, storage, realtimedb work not sure what I'm missing. I followed The [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype?database=Firestore) to set up.

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider } from "firebase/app-check";
import { getDatabase, connectDatabaseEmulator } from "firebase/database";
import {
  getAuth,
  connectAuthEmulator,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";
import {
  getFunctions,
  connectFunctionsEmulator,
  httpsCallable,
} from "firebase/functions";
import { getStorage, connectStorageEmulator } from "firebase/storage";
import Constants from "expo-constants";

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: Constants.manifest.extra.apiKey,
  authDomain: Constants.manifest.extra.authDomain,
  dataBaseURL: Constants.manifest.extra.databaseURL,
  projectId: Constants.manifest.extra.projectId,
  storageBucket: Constants.manifest.extra.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: Constants.manifest.extra.messagingSenderId,
  appId: Constants.manifest.extra.appId,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export const firestore = {
  instance: () => {
    return getFirestore(app);
  },
  connectFirestoreEmulator: (host, port) => {
    return connectFirestoreEmulator(getFirestore(app), host, port);
  },
};


if (__DEV__) {
  try {
    firestore.connectFirestoreEmulator("localhost", "8080");

    console.log("====================================");
    console.log("connected to emulators....");
    console.log("====================================");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log(error, "error connectiong emulators");
    console.log("====================================");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the error seems to happen only in Firestore, I have followed the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#instrument_your_app_to_talk_to_the_emulators) related to using the Firestore emulator, and my app successfully connects to the local emulator and retrieves local data.

I’m not sure if the way you export the Firestore instance is causing the issue, but the documentation shows that the function must be imported and used, passing the Firestore instance as an argument. This is the sample code I tested:

**firestore-config.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    // Configuration keys
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
```

**app.js**

```
import { firestore } from "./firestore-config";
import { getDoc, doc, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";
import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  try{
    connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, "localhost", "8080");
    console.log("connected");

    const docRef = doc(firestore, "localTest", "localTestDoc");
    const getData = async () => {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      console.log(docSnap.data());
    }
  
    getData();

  }
  catch(err){
    console.log("error: ", err)
  }
  return <div className="App"></div>;
}
```

I am able to see my data coming from the emulated Firestore as output. It would also be useful to see a full error stack trace, since the error from the title is not really that descriptive.